# BeautifulSoup Python .text method doesn't return proper text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape soccer results from a website. I get the results with the html and when I try to remove them with .text I get strange output. I use the parent method to get the parent HTML element for the whole score.

The scraper script:

```
        response = requests.get(url)
        html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        type(html_soup)

        results = html_soup.findAll('strong',text="East Wall Rovers")
        chosen_team_results=[]

        for result in results:
            chosen_team_results.append(result.parent.text)
        print(chosen_team_results)
```

HTML:

```
<p class="zeta"><strong>
            Killester Donnycarney FC</strong>
            1
            <strong>Cherry Orchard</strong>
            2
                        </p>
<p class="zeta"><strong>
            Ballymun United</strong>
            2
            <strong>Bluebell United</strong>
            1
                        </p>
```

OUTPUT:

```
'\r\n\t\t\tValeview Shankill\r\n\t\t\t1\r\n\t\t\tEast Wall Rovers\r\n\t\t\t5\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\tMarks Celtic FC\r\n\t\t\t0\r\n\t\t\tEast Wall Rovers\r\n\t\t\t5\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\tBlessington FC\r\n\t\t\t0\r\n\t\t\tEast Wall Rovers\r\n\t\t\t5\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\tParkvale FC\r\n\t\t\t2\r\n\t\t\tEast Wall Rovers\r\n\t\t\t1\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\tBoyne Rovers\r\n\t\t\t1\r\n\t\t\tEast Wall Rovers\r\n\t\t\t1\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t'
```

I expect the results to be in plain text just the teams and the points.

Comment: can you share your url?

Comment: Well, this is plain text - your html does have all those newlines (`\n`) and tabs (`\t`). Print a specific string, not the whole list, and you'll see. ;)

Comment: Given your posted html, what exactly is your desired output?

Comment: share the url if possible. Make sure your HTML shown corresponds with the actual/expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the blank space, I recommend you do something like this:

```python
for result in results:
    chosen_team_results.append(''.join(str(result.parent.text).split()))
print(chosen_team_results)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a .strip() method to the string/text so it displays only the text without the \r\n\t\t\t (linebreaks etc.)

for example:

```python
songs = soup.find_all(name="h3", id="title-of-a-story")

songs_text = [song.getText().strip() for song in songs ]
```